# How can a website survive an untrusted environment?

Tags: security, windows

Let's say I have an internal website that holds pretty important data (well, contest strategies for stuff like FIRST), which I am bound to host on a Windows server with literally no security. I can't access anything but the public directory.

We have script kiddies from nearby schools constantly trying to get a competitive advantage by hacking into the servers and stealing information.

About 30% sure there's viruses on the system too.

Is it possible to build a website that could survive such treatment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope a virus could issue this command: `del /S *.*` on your website directory.

Anytime the server's OS is compromised there's really nothing you can do to protect against it.

Comment: How close can I get?

Comment: The smartest thing you can do is create a solid backup plan. Most backup plans include a secured server of some sort unless the website doesn't change often. If the doesn't change often then you can keep the backup on a flash drive.